# How to delete null column data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-delete

In my stored procedure I have a temp table where I have data like below:

[image]

I am getting 2 rows for some employees one having emp name and other are null.

Now I need to delete the row for employee if its having duplicate rows with null emp name.

We don't need to delete if its the single row with null. I just need to delete the highlighted ones.

Please help what is the where condition here

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for name with the `is null` operator, and have another `exists` condition to check for a corresponsing id with a non-null name:

```sql
DELETE a
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  emp_name IS NULL AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   mytable b
               WHERE  b.emp_name IS NOT NULL AND a.emp_id = b.emp_id)
```

Comment: Hi @mureinik I tried your approach but getting the error.I have edited the question and added the error.Could you please check and help

Comment: @vissubabu forgot the `as`, mea culpa. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi @Mureinik though I added the as I am getting error as Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 626
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'..

Comment: It should be `DELETE a FROM MyTable a...` (though I would also use `MT` as the alias).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, `DELETE` with `FROM` syntax is a bit different. Try one of these:

```
delete @Results
from @Results r
where
    r.AffectedEndUserName is null
    and exists  (
                    select
                        1
                    from @Results rr
                    where
                        rr.AffectedEndUserName is not null and rr.EmpId = r.EmpId
                );

delete r
from @Results r
    inner join @Results rr on rr.EmpId = r.EmpId and rr.AffectedEndUserName is not null
where
    r.AffectedEndUserName is null;
```

I would prefer the latter; much cleaner.